# PHP/XML Garbled text

Tags: php, xml

I'm using the following class:

```
class rss {
    public function rssReader($rssLocalSource,$rssSetLimit){
        $rss = new DOMDocument();
        $rss->load($rssLocalSource);
        $feed = array();

        $countMaxArticles = array();
        foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
            $item = array ( 
                'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                );
                $countMaxArticles[] = 1;
                array_push($feed, $item);
            }
            $totalNumArticles = count($countMaxArticles);
            $setRssLimit = min($totalNumArticles,$rssSetLimit);

            echo '<div class="rss-links">';
            echo '<ul>';
            for($x=0;$x<$setRssLimit;$x++) {
                //$title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
                $title = utf8_encode ($feed[$x]['title']);
                $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
                echo '<li><a target="_blank" href="'.$link.'">'.$title.'</a></li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
}
```

The above code basically reads the title of newspaper headlines and outputs a link.

The text in the XML file isn't garbled. Though when the above code reads the XML file, the text is garbled

e.g. The title

> Banks Need ‘Hybrid Approach to Blockchain Technology’: Ripple’s Marcus Treacher

is being out put as

> Banks Need Ã¢Â€Â˜Hybrid Approach to Blockchain TechnologyÃ¢Â€Â™: RippleÃ¢Â€Â™s Marcus Treacher

Comment: Specify your question, please.

Comment: You're encoding UTF8 as Latin1 to UTF-8, don't do that.

Comment: @ThW How do I fix it?

Comment: Without showing the XML you are processing nobody is going to be able to help you. It seems like an encoding issue of the source document.

Comment: I already solved it. The solution is below. Thank you just the same.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing

```
$title = utf8_encode ($feed[$x]['title']);
```

to

```
$title = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $feed[$x]['title']);
```